# React native PanResponder snap effect after using Animated.spring

Tags: react-native, animation

I'm working on adding my own bottom sliding drawer.
Everything works well when I set the values and I don't have a snap effect as I initialize the offset when I grant the pan.

When my drawer is below certain height I want it to close with a nice spring animation.
The problem is when I set the animatedHeight variable using Animated.spring, I have a snap effect the next time I start panning I can't get rid of the snap effect.

The effect never disappear once I used the spring animation. Even if use slideTo again.
Please help

Code is below

```
import React, {
  ReactNode,
  createContext,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import {Animated, PanResponder, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import WindowDimensions from '../utils/WindowDimensions';
import Row from '../components/new/Row';
import {VoidFunctionT} from '../types/VoidFunctionT';
import style from '../style';

type BottomSlidingDrawerOptions = {
  maxHeight: number;
  maxOverHeightDelta: number;
  closeBelowHeight: number;
};

const BottomSlidingDrawerContext = createContext<
  | undefined
  | {
      closeDrawer: (
        animationEndCallback?: VoidFunctionT<{
          finished: boolean;
        }>,
      ) => void;
      drawerContent: ReactNode;
      drawerContentSetter: VoidFunctionT<ReactNode>;
      slideTo: VoidFunctionT<number>;
      setOptions: VoidFunctionT<Partial<BottomSlidingDrawerOptions>>;
    }
>(undefined);

export function BottomSlidingDrawerProvider({children}: {children: ReactNode}) {
  const [drawerContent, drawerContentSetter] = useState<ReactNode>();
  const options = useRef<BottomSlidingDrawerOptions>({
    maxHeight: WindowDimensions.height,
    maxOverHeightDelta: 30,
    closeBelowHeight: 110,
  });
  const animatedHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(0))
    .current as Animated.Value & {_value: number};

  const slideTo = useCallback(
    (
      value: number,
      animationEndCallback?: VoidFunctionT<{finished: boolean}>,
    ) =>
      //   Animated.spring(animatedHeight, {
      //     toValue: -value,
      //     useNativeDriver: true,
      //   }).start(animationEndCallback),
      animatedHeight.setValue(-value),
    [animatedHeight],
  );
  const closeDrawer = useCallback(
    (animationEndCallback?: VoidFunctionT<{finished: boolean}>) =>
      slideTo(0, animationEndCallback),
    [slideTo],
  );

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () =>
        animatedHeight.setOffset(animatedHeight._value),
      onPanResponderMove: (_evt, gestureState) => {
        const {dy} = gestureState;
        animatedHeight.setValue(dy);
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        animatedHeight.flattenOffset();

        if (
          Math.abs(animatedHeight._value) < options.current.closeBelowHeight
        ) {
          Animated.spring(animatedHeight, {
            toValue: 0,
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }).start();
        } else {
          animatedHeight.setValue(
            Math.max(animatedHeight._value, -options.current.maxHeight),
          );
        }
      },
    }),
  ).current;

  const store = {
    closeDrawer,
    drawerContent,
    drawerContentSetter,
    setOptions: useCallback(
      (drawerOptions: Partial<BottomSlidingDrawerOptions>) =>
        (options.current = {...options.current, ...drawerOptions}),
      [],
    ),
    slideTo,
  };

  return (
    <BottomSlidingDrawerContext.Provider value={store}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          ...viewStyle.drawer,
          transform: [{translateY: animatedHeight}],
        }}>
        <Row hcenter>
          <View style={style.paddingAll4} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
            <View style={viewStyle.handle} />
          </View>
        </Row>
        {drawerContent}
      </Animated.View>
      {children}
    </BottomSlidingDrawerContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useBottomSlidingDrawer() {
  const context = React.useContext(BottomSlidingDrawerContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      'useBottomSlidingDrawer must be used within a BottomSlidingDrawerProvider',
    );
  }
  return context;
}

const viewStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  handle: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    width: 45,
    height: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  drawer: {
    backgroundColor: '#f0f7f4',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.05)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 100,
    height: WindowDimensions.height,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingTop: 8,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: WindowDimensions.height,
    width: WindowDimensions.width,
    zIndex: 100,
  },
});
```